# How to find rectangular areas in Numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy matrix representing picture pixel matrix. This picture contains letters and I want to find all vertical strokes and replace their cells' values.

simple letter "r" shape might look like this then

][image]
left: input bitmap

right: expected output, note that the horizontal stroke was ignored. Magine that such letters can be infinite with unknown stem width. But let's say that we will always know how thick the stroke is, we just don't know how tall it is.

```
[
[255, 255, 255, 255],
[255,   0,   0, 255],
[255,   0, 255, 255],
[255,   0, 255, 255],
[255,   0, 255, 255],
[255, 255, 255, 255]
]
```

How would you find all vertical rectangles? So the output would look like this

```
[
[False, False, False, False],
[False,  True, False, False],
[False,  True, False, False],
[False,  True, False, False],
[False,  True, False, False],
[False, False, False, False]
```

Thanks

Comment: I am a bit confused by the definition of "vertical stroke". If it means any vertical consecutive "0"s that have a length of more than 1, and you don't care that much about performance, a nest for loop that scans the matrix vertically should work? Please better explain what exactly you are trying to detect.

Comment: can you include a sample dataset and then include what your expected results would look like?

Comment: Hi @Jaxon, I have changed the description and made it a bit more proper

Comment: [This](https://www.science-emergence.com/Articles/Implementing-a-simple-python-code-to-detect-straight-lines-using-Hough-transform/) might be a bit too much for the problem, but have a look.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the most efficient and not the most general approach, but it works:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.signal import convolve2d

image = np.asarray( [
                [255, 255, 255, 255],
                [255,   0,   0, 255],
                [255,   0, 255, 255],
                [255,   0, 255, 255],
                [255,   0, 255, 255],
                [255, 255, 255, 255]
                ] )

imageI = 255 - image
kernel=np.ones(3).reshape(3,1)

out= convolve2d( imageI, kernel, mode='full' )

out2 = out > 255

print out2[ 1 : len(image) + 1 ]
```

giving as desired:

```
 >> [[False False False False]
 >> [False  True False False]
 >> [False  True False False]
 >> [False  True False False]
 >> [False  True False False]
 >> [False False False False]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use a vertical median filter:

```
scipy.ndimage.filters.median_filter(
    a, size=(3, 1)
)
# array([[255, 255, 255, 255],
#        [255,   0, 255, 255],
#        [255,   0, 255, 255],
#        [255,   0, 255, 255],
#        [255,   0, 255, 255],
#        [255, 255, 255, 255]])
```